# Iterate over uneven array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, if-statement

So I have a dataset of 16 items, I want to loop through them every 5 items after the first set of 6 so the columns are 6 5 5.

Initially I tried something like this, but then I remembered I had that one orphaned item.

```
if(thisI <= 6) {
  y = prevtitle.position[0];
} elseif(thisI % 5 == 0) {
  y = prevtitle.position[0] + w + (p *3);
} else {
  y = prevtitle.position[0];
}
```

Not sure if there is a simple way to do the first 6 and then the next ones in five without a bunch of nested if statements.

Comment: can you show your dataset array?

Comment: So there was an answer in the comments here that seemed like it was what I needed, but when I came back and refreshed it was gone. I'm not looking to split the array into chunks.

Comment: I updated my answer. Is that what you're looking for? An abbreviated way to set your `y` variable based on the index?

Answer (score 0):

Using [`Array#splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice):

```js
const splitArr = (arr = []) => {
  const array = [...arr];
  const res = array.length ? [array.splice(0, 6)] : [];
  while(array.length) res.push(array.splice(0, 5));
  return res;
}

console.log( splitArr([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16]) );
```

Comment: I'm not looking to split the array into more arrays.

Comment: What's the expected result for this array?

Answer (score 0):

Would a simple ternary expression work for you?

```
let num = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16]
num.forEach((n,i) => {
  y = (i<=6 || i % 5 == 0) ? prevtitle.position[0] : prevtitle.position[0] + w + (p *3) ;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I presume that you're skipping the first position, and jumps directly to the 6th position.

Just use a normal for loop.

1. Calculate the remainder for the number of steps that you will make. 16 % 5 results in 1 remainder.
2. `step - countForZero + remainder` sets the start point in the for loop.
3. `i += step` replaces the typical `i++` in the for loop.

The method below can make any kind of leap, and it doesn't matter how many items there are in the array.

```js
let num = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16];

function getEvery(step, arr) {
  let newArr = [],
      remainder = arr.length % step,
      countForZero = 1;

  for (let i = step - countForZero + remainder; i < arr.length; i += step) {
     newArr.push(arr[i]);
  }

  return newArr;
}

console.log( getEvery(5, num) );
```